# Ext.Date.format wrong format

Tags: date, extjs, extjs4, date-format

I am facing an issue in ExtJS with the Date format.

I'm using `Ext.Date.format(value, 'm/d/Y h:i:s a')` where the value is a date from the database.

While saving a Date `06/29/2018 12:15:00 am` to DB it's storing as `2018-06-26 07:30:00`
I am getting the Date from Database as `2018-06-28T18:45:00.000Z` when converting to Ext.Date.format it changes to `06/29/2018 12:15:00 am`.

I need store the date to be same as UI(06/29/2018 12:15:00 am) in db. Is there anyway?

Thanks

Comment: The date is still the same, it's only displayed in a different format. I think this is issue in your DB not ExtJS.

Comment: The date is not the same, it's three days off.

Comment: It's added 18hr when I pass to API.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might not be ExtJS itself nor your database, but the fact that your server and browser are on different timezones (i.e. Server in USA and browsing in Europe). I can think of two solutions:

1) Store the timezones in the database along with the dates. The record would look something like this: 2018-06-28T18:45:00.000Z+10:00. Use .NET's `DateTimeOffset` type in your C# code for this alternative.

2) What you can do instead is to convert all dates to UTC in the server side. Probably calling `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` will suffice, but you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992905/convert-datetime-string-to-utc) for more details.

Then you can use a library like moment.js which helps a lot with date and time manipulation/formatting to display the dates in the user's local timezone.

Comment: What you can do instead is to convert all dates to UTC in the server side.** For this do have any reference?.**

Comment: What server-side language/db are you using?

Comment: c#/postgresql we are using.

Comment: Please refer to my updated answer for more information.